# Apache PdfBox Gray/faint underscores 2.0.26

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

The problem is that when our PDFBOX prints to the form using Autosize for Courier font defined as: "/Cour 0 Tf 0 0 0 rg"

The underscores appear faint or grayed out so that users may not see them.

I have tried looking through all relevant stack overflow articles and Apache release notes to see if this has ever been mentioned or fixed but I cannot find anything on this topic.

[image: 1][image: 3][image: 2]

Comment: The mailto is not a space, it was entered as test_test@test.com

Also the 0 from what I know signifies the variable/autosize for PDFBox

Comment: @KJ if you can see the previous comment

Comment: What kind of printer is this (label printer?) and what code do you use for printing? With dpi or without? If with dpi, what value? Btw the current version is 2.0.30.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr This is just an image rendered in the browser. So its not actually being printed. These are mainly created and stored virtually. 

We are using Java for the printing to the PDF and I do not see any settings for DPI currently being set. Would setting the DPI possibly be the issue? 

I believe I tried upgrading locally to 2.0.30 but saw the same result

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I did notice when I set the font size directly to font size 12 for instance the underscore is the same color as the rest of the text. The problem is that this allows for users to overfill the field or run out of space. But when I use text that is autosizing this is the current result. Also we are not converting the PDF to a PNG. We are printing to a PDF that can be downloaded, or printed.

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample PDF file for investigation?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr it does appear they are slightly being cut off. I will try and attach another photo

Comment: @TilmanHausherr after it hits the end of the box it does appear to autosize down as intended. If you can see the 3rd attached image

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have tried 2.0.30 and am getting the same result

Comment: Sorry I see you've mentioned that before. I've asked on the dev mailing list.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Sorry for the delay. I tried uploading the PDF but we flatten our PDF fields so when I uploaded the file the fields were inaccessible. I can upload an unflattened version but the fields will be editable and not represent what users are receiving on their end.

I have been conducting a lot of testing and from what I can see this is an issue with the Courier font set. When I use all the same code, but Helvetica it prints the underscores clearly on the PDF. When I use Courier though this issue is very prevalent.

Comment: We need the unflattened file. The appearance stream is calculated by PDFBox before the flattening, based on field data. Alternatively create a form file yourself with the `CreateSimpleForm.java` program from the source code download.  https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateSimpleForm.java?revision=1881001&view=markup

Comment: The unflattened PDF file doesn't have any acroform fields.

Comment: I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5736
@Chawk can we add the form to the ticket?

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun please feel free to add it! Or let me know if I should

Comment: @Chawk - I think that currently you have to live with the result. I did some investigation with regards to the different font information available in the form. Using some characteristics from the font itself and not relying on the font description gives a better result but still off to what Acrobat calculates.

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun this is actually a pretty large issue for our user base. These are official government forms so if the underscores "_" cannot be printed properly to the form and this occurs in an email address. The officials would be unable to contact the users from their email address as it would appear as spaces on the form.

We also cannot really migrate font sets as we need a universal monospace font which courier is. Are there any possible work arounds for this?

We also have to use autosizing as emails could in theory be extremely long.

Comment: @Chawk - could you use a different font to the Courier Standard font?

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun No unfortunately as previously stated we need to use a monospace font for our solution

Comment: @TilmanHausherr 

Essentially as a work around any "email" field I have defaulted to a different font type (Helvetica) to get these underscores printed for these fields.

I was wondering if either of you may be able to give me more information on how to designate a PDTextField vs PDVariableText when the PDF is being created. Is there a setting on the actual PDF's themselves? I was reading the documentation but I am unsure what gives a field this categorization.

Comment: That isn't something to be answered in a comment. You'd have to read the PDF specification or have a look at the few examples in the source code download. Start with `CreateSimpleForm.java`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. In my case, the Courier New font is also used, but the size is strictly 18pt. After fluttering, the underscore character simply disappeared from the PDF. During the experiments, I found out that it's a combination of the height of the input field and the size of the character. The only solution for me was to increase the height of the field and change the position of the field along the Y axis so that it meets the requirements and everything is displayed correctly. Therefore, I suggest that you specify the font size for the email field and increase the height of the field.

Comment: @KJ Yes, I encountered this behavior during the development phase. Moreover, if I'm not mistaken, the difference was even within the same document viewer, but on different operating systems (Win/Unix). Therefore, we had to use Flatten() and deny the user the ability to edit directly into the PDF.